# Por qué Chart.js no se carga?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

tengo problema con un chart.js que se dibuja recién después de realizar una acción. Por ejemplo, cuando abro el inspector en el navegador o cuando oculto el sidebar.
Lo que quiero es que al ingresar a la página esté dibujado el gráfico.
El código es muy similar al que proporciona la documentación.

```
<div id="contenedor_distribucion_por_unidad">
   <canvas id="distribucion_por_unidad"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
function distribucion() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('distribucion_por_unidad').getContext('2d');
    var titulo = [];
    var cantidad = [];
    var colores = [];
    var blanco = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "controller/estadisticas/distribucionController.php",
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function (resp) {
        var data = JSON.parse(resp);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            titulo.push(data[i].unidad);
            cantidad.push(data[i].contador);
            colores.push(colorRGB());
            blanco.push("#fff");
        }
    });
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: {
            labels: titulo,
            datasets: [{
                data: cantidad,
                backgroundColor: colores,
                borderColor: blanco,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
}

if ($("#contenedor_distribucion_por_unidad").length) {
    distribucion();
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar en qué parte tienes agregado el código javascript que compartes? ¿Al final del documento HTML? ¿Antes o después del HTML del `<canvas>`? ¿En un archivo javascript externo cargado con o sin `defer` o `async`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia el código js está en un archivo a parte. Lo cargo al final del html después del `<canvas>`, sin defer ni async.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de invocar la función cuando tu contenedor tenga algún valor, debes de hacerlo desde que se carga y está listo el DOM con JQuery, por ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   distribucion();
} )
```